# Fix Array out of bounds Exception New Array Exception

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

When I try to run my code it tells me I have multiple Array out of bounds exception in Caluclate Fitness, and Selection any ideas to help me thanks. It says the error is in line 67 I believe one of the errors and 37 of my Main Class (Genetic Algorithm). The Individual class seems to be fine I expect the problem lies in how I define my functions but I dont know to fix this error. Ive starred the error it is the selection array. ON the line in selection it says Array out of bounds 50 which i guess means it thinks the i in the array is not declared but I have declared it

```
package genetic.algorithm;

import static genetic.algorithm.GeneticAlgorithm.Selection;
import static genetic.algorithm.GeneticAlgorithm.n_population;
import static genetic.algorithm.Individual.N;
import static genetic.algorithm.Individual.fitness;
import static genetic.algorithm.Individual.gene;
import java.util.Random;

public class GeneticAlgorithm {

    static int P = 50;
    static int i = 0;
    static int j = 0;
    static Random rand = new Random();
    static Individual[] n_population = new Individual[P];
    static Individual[] offspring = new Individual[P];

    public static Individual[] population() {
        int rn = rand.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i < P; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                n_population[i].gene[j] = rn % 2;
            }
            n_population[i].fitness = 0;
        }
        return n_population;
    }

    public static int CalculateFitness(int[] gene) {
        gene = new int[N];
        fitness = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < N; ) {
            for (i = 0; i < P; ) {
                if (n_population[i].gene[j] != 0) n_population[i].fitness++;
            }
        }
        return fitness;
    }

    public static Individual[] Selection(Individual[] n_population) {
        n_population = new Individual[P];
        offspring = new Individual[P];
        fitness = 0;
        int rands = rand.nextInt();
        int parent1 = rands % P;
        int parent2 = rands % P;
        for (i = 0; i < P; i++) {
           **if (n_population[parent2].fitness >= n_population[parent1].fitness)**
                offspring[i] = n_population[parent1];
            else {
                offspring[i] = n_population[parent2];**
            }
        }
        return offspring;
    }

    public static Individual[] Crossover(Individual[] n_population) {
        int rands = rand.nextInt();
        n_population = new Individual[P];
        offspring = new Individual[P];
        gene = new int[N];
        int[] temp_gene1 = new int[N];
        int[] temp_gene2 = new int[N];
        int parent1 = rands % P;
        int parent2 = rands % P;
        int crossoverPoint = rands % N;

        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (j > crossoverPoint) {
                temp_gene1[j] = n_population[parent2].gene[j];
                temp_gene2[j] = n_population[parent1].gene[j];
            } else {
               * temp_gene1[j] = n_population[parent1].gene[j]*;
                temp_gene2[j] = n_population[parent2].gene[j];
            }
        }

        if (CalculateFitness(temp_gene1) >= CalculateFitness(temp_gene2))
            offspring[i] = n_population[parent1];
        else {
            offspring[i] = n_population[parent2];
        }
        return offspring;
    }

    public static Individual[] Mutation(Individual[] n_population) {
        double x = 0.1;
        double y = 0.107;
        double randoms = rand.nextDouble();
        for (i = 0; i < P; ) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; ) {
                if ((x < randoms) && (randoms < y)) {
                    if (n_population[i].gene[j] == 0)
                        n_population[i].gene[j] = 1;
                    else {
                        n_population[i].gene[j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                offspring[i] = n_population[i];
            }
        }
        return offspring;
    }

    public static int Mean(Individual[] n_population) {
        int mean_fitness = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < P; ) {
            mean_fitness += n_population[i].fitness;
        }
        return (mean_fitness / P);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        n_population = population();

        for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            n_population = Selection(n_population);
            n_population = Crossover(n_population);
            n_population = Mutation(n_population);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please format your code, highlight line number where the NPE is coming from

Comment: Please provide the definition of `Individual` and the full stack trace of your thrown exception to assist in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: At a glance, as noted by @LouFranco, it looks like line 43, `n_population = new Individual[P];`, overwrites `n_population` with a new array of `null`s, resulting in line 50, `if (n_population[parent2].fitness >= n_population[parent1].fitness)`, trying to access the `fitness` property of a `null` `Individual`.

Comment: Aside from that the `rands % P` expressions may have negative values as `rands` may be negative. That will result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s for negative `rands` values, which happened in the few runs of your code with an assumed `Individual` class that I tried.

Comment: Final comment: it looks like `Individual.fitness` and `Individual.genes` are static - i.e. shared by all `Individual`s. Based on a read of the code using `Individual` and the name `Individual` I suspect that those fields should not be `static`.

Comment: New problem when I run it nothing happens when I ran it through the debugger it says "No variables to display because there is no current thread."

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
 public static Individual[] Selection(Individual[] n_population) {
    n_population = new Individual[P];
```

So, you pass in `n_population` and then immediately hide it with a declaration of an array with all nulls in it.  So, any `n_population[i]` in it is null.  I expect that you get a NullPointerException when you check the .fitness in it later (not out of bounds)

I think you should delete `n_population = new Individual[P];`

Comment: Problem still exists. But at least it would stop one later on

Comment: Please provide more details on the problem that is happening. A stack trace (full error output) would be a good start. :)

Comment: New problem when I run it nothing happens when I ran it through the debugger it says "No variables to display because there is no current thread." –